# Can't find <RestKit/RestKit.h> when I am done with the installation and configuration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, frameworks

I have followed the exactly same steps as bellow.
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x

However, I got an error when I build the project which is clang: error: ***

> no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/*********(My Apple ID)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoffeeShop-dsxackkfpgdbdphjbiezjinakwam/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKit/RestKit'

---

I guess maybe there is something wrong with the **Header Search Path**. I use "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers" as input.
However, I try every possible path I know. The problem remain the same.